# Geometric series, find the general form

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series that I found is $1+a$, $1+a+a^2$, $1+a+a^2+a^3$,...

Although I can see the pattern, but I am not sure how to derive the general form in terms of n for this series? Anyone can guide me the systematic approach of deriving this? Thank you!

Comment: This is not a geometric series as the ratio of successive terms is not constant.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$a^2-1=(a-1)\color{red}{(1+a)}$$
$$a^3-1=(a-1)\color{red}{(1+a+a^2)}$$
In fact, in general:
$$a^n-1=(a-1)\color{red}{(1+a+...+a^{n-1})}$$

Answer (score 0):

$1+a+a^2+...+a^{n-1} = (a^n-1)/(a-1)$